# How I can uploads text files with HTML 5?

Tags: php, jquery, html, upload

I have following problem. I use this tutorial to creating a multiple file uploader: 
http://tutorialzine.com/2011/09/html5-file-upload-jquery-php/

But this code uploding only IMAGES. I want this code to upload text files, not images. Is there a possibility to happen.

In file script.js i changed a type of file with this code, but don't work.

```
        // Called before each upload is started
    beforeEach: function(file){
        if(!value.match(/\.(txt)|(csv)$/)){
            alert('Only TXT and CSV files!');

            // Returning false will cause the
            // file to be rejected
            return false;
        }
    },
```

The error message after uploadied files is "Your browser does not support HTML5 file uploads!"
What changes should I make to work correctly?
Thanks in advace !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9658929/trying-to-upload-multiple-images-using-xhr-2-and-php

Comment: Copying scripts is all well and good, but actually learning how to program properly will be far more beneficial IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.script-tutorials.com/pure-html5-file-upload/